# Passing variables between functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I'm trying to make a simple on-focus clearer/on-blur restorer for forms on a site and I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.form-text').focus(function(keeper) {
        var keeper = $(this).attr('value');
        if($(this).val() == keeper) {
            $(this).val(''); 
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.form-text').blur(function(keeper) {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            keeper;
        }
        return false;
    }); 

 });
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: what exactly isnt working? also why are you always returning false?

Comment: What's the blur function supposed to do? It just references the parameter and doesn't do anything with it. Did you mean to do what you do with the empty string in the focus function?

Comment: Nadir: it's not restoring the original value of name on blur.

Comment: Dave: it's supposed to clear the value of an input object in a form. The code does that, but it doesn't restore the value on blur.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just make `keeper` in a outer scope, no need to be global.
And `var keeper = $(this).attr('value'); if($(this).val() == keeper)` will always true, so that is not necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var keeper;

    $('.form-text').focus(function() {
        keeper = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    });

    $('.form-text').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val(keeper);
        }
        return false;
    }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery provides a [method to store data for you](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

Set:

```
$("#selector").data('name', 'value');
```

Get:
`var path = $(this).data('name'); // Get the stored resul`t

Answer (score 2):

you might want to make `var keeper` global.

you can use this

```
var keeper = "";

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.form-text').focus(function(keeper) {
        keeper = $(this).attr('value');
        if($(this).val() == keeper) {
            $(this).val(''); 
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.form-text').blur(function(keeper) {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            keeper;
        }
        return false;
    }); 

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: aren't $(this).attr('value') and $(this(.val() referring to the the same value, or am I missing something?

In the "blur" event, aren't you using "keeper" as if it were a method, not a variable?